# How to check if an element has a dynamically added class and based on that apply some style in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Hi I have the following html:

```
<div class="col-sm-20">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
      <label class="btn btn-primary demo-review" ng-model="demo.title" btn-radio="'{{::demo.demoinfo.title}}'">
          {{::demo.demoinfo.title}}
          <i class="check-circle btn-success" aria-hidden="false" ng-if="'0' == '0'"></i>
      </label>

      <label class="btn btn-primary demo-review " ng-model="demo.title" btn-radio="'{{::demo.demoform.title}}'">
          {{::demo.demoform.title}}
          <i class="check-circle btn-success" aria-hidden="false" ng-if="'1' == '0'"></i>
      </label>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Now in the above,the labels are added with a class called "active" whenever a particular label is selected; i.e., this class 'active' is dynamically added.
And  I want to show/hide the `<i class="check-circle btn-success" aria-hidden="false" ng-if=" '1' == '0' ">` based on whether the label has class 'select' or not. So basicallly I want to update my ng-if based on the existence of the class 'active'.
I think I am pretty close:

```
<label class="btn btn-primary demo-review"  ng-model="demo.title"  btn-radio="'{{::demo.demoinfo.title}}'">{{::demo.demoinfo.title}}<i class="amds-check-circle  pull-right-sm " aria-hidden="false" ng-if=" angular.element($this).hasClass('active') "></i></label>
```

Basically in the ng-if I am trying to check if the label element has class 'active'.I might be little away, may be syntax is wrong.Can anyone pls help?

Is it possible?
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am kind of newbie, can you pls elaborate?

Comment: Can't you just use CSS? `label.demo-review:not(.active) .check-circle { display: none; }`

Comment: Good idea. But here, based on label has active class or not, I want to add check-circle class to the i element, not on the label.Any idea how that can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you actually want to do is conditionally apply a class to your element(s).

Using `ng-class`, you can do this:

```
<label ng-class="{ 'selected': demo.isSelected }">
    <i ng-class="{ 'check-circle': demo.isSelected }" class="btn-success" aria-hidden="false"></i>
</label>
```

In this case, only if your model `demo.isSelected` is `true`, the `selected` class will be applied to the label and also the `check-circle` class applied to the `<i>` element.

Comment: Its not working. Moreover,its not adding a class selected, its like adding the element <i class="check-circle btn-success" aria-hidden="false" > if the label has a class called 'select', which is added dynamically.

Comment: Then please show how the selected class is added to thr label dynamically. I dont see it in your code fragment.

Comment: Since you don't seem to want to provide any additional information, I've updated my answer based on some additional comments that you provided against the original question.  Rather than trying to add a class to your icon based on a class present in the label, use your view model to determine if the label is "selected" overall, and apply the requisite classes to them using `ng-class` as demonstrated in my answer.  If this **still** doesn't solve your issue, then please update the question with additional detail on how you are dynamically applying the `selected` class to the label.